# How to create fake ParseObject in Parse

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

Consider I have a list of objects like this, binded to a ListView:

```cs
[ParseClassName("Guest")]
public class Guest : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("driver")]
    public bool Driver
    {
        get { return GetProperty<bool>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("user")]
    public User User
    {
        get { return GetProperty<User>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }
 }
```

In Visual Studio 2015, I'd like, via binding, to show fake data into designer. To do this, I definied fake

```
public class FakeGuest : Guest
{
    public FakeGuest(int i)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        Driver = rand.NextDouble() <= 0.5 ? true : false;
        User = new FakeUser(i);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when that constructor is called, `new FakeGuest(2)`, Parse throws an exception saying:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Parse.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: You must create this type of ParseObject using
>   ParseObject.Create() or the proper subclass.

How can I create fake data that derives from ParseObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create `ParseObject` in a way you are trying to. 
You can, however, go around this using static "factory" method, e.g.

```
var fake = FakeGuest.Create(1);
```

where `FakeGuest` would be

```
public class FakeGuest : ParseObject
{
    private static readonly Random Rand = new Random();

    public static ParseObject Create(int id)
    {
        var guest = Create("Guest");
        guest.Add("driver", Rand.NextDouble() <= 0.5);

        var user = Create("User");
        user.Add("id", id);

        guest.Add("user", user);

        return guest;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I create it from within a ParseObject subclass?

Comment: Let's consider Guest. In the code you posted you shown how to create a Guest outside the class. What if I would like to make a subclass of Guest, like FakeGuest, with the idea of writing: new FakeGuest(). What should I have to put into FakeGuest constructor?